# What's the block gas limit of the ThunderCore chain?

Tags: thundercore

- Is it true that the maximum amount of gas units that could be used by transactions contained in a single block could change over time and be different on different EVM compatible chains?
- What's the `block gas limit` of the ThunderCore chain specifically?
- Can I obtain the `block gas limit` programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the block gas limit of `thunder-mainet` is **100M gas units**.

## Longer Answer

- The block gas limit indeed could indeed change over time for the same chain
- The block gas limit of `thunder-mainnet` (https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com) is 100M gas units
- To obtain the latest `block gas limit` of an EVM compatible chain, fetch the latest block header via `eth_getBlockByNumber` and read the `gasLimit` field:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["latest", false],"id":1}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com | jq '.result.gasLimit' | python -c 'import sys; print(int(sys.stdin.read().strip()[1:-1], base=16))'
```

## Output

```
100000000
```

## Block Header

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "difficulty": "0x9103000002000000cd0f00009103000002000000cc0f0000",
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": "0x5f5e100",
    "gasUsed": "0x8da5d",
    "hash": "0xd3b407d7caee8cb351cc2ddd4315ab08de116da13defa98d0988fbc876b0c508",
    "logsBloom": "0x000000000000000000000000000000020000000001000000000000000000000000400000000000400000000000880000400000000000000000000000000020000400000000001000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000800a0000000000000100000800000000000000000000000018000001000000000001000004000240000000000000000000000000000000000400000000040000000020200000000000000000000000000000100000000800022002000000002002000000000000000200002000000000000004000000000000000020000000000000000100000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000220",
    "miner": "0xc4f3c85bb93f33a485344959cf03002b63d7c4e3",
    "mixHash": "0x1ff8b209ed7b610a4e7c0457e169894894bfeb4ab0e2e2345a67a8a80f341ae0",
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000fcd",
    "number": "0x28de50c",
    "parentHash": "0xd67bac08ffd4ede2335e9481e3037e061ee94ceb4585050284fde03d9969e3e3",
    "receiptsRoot": "0xa5013034e668c9c35fc9b5c3c3c8cb039320c19a2067bdcbd898f0de53a35459",
    "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
    "size": "0x57b",
    "stateRoot": "0x33d8e304800f11556826625f8d9f5d0017855909d9c86db04e99e93fe9376231",
    "timestamp": "0x5f06f91f",
    "totalDifficulty": "0x45cae70bf7fe32e14a93365747cae67af4fe32e04a9335cb758141",
    "transactions": [
      "0xcc8105b70d4e8167046f5bbaef63fcf549cf52b8988c500e176b8281e7eed5d5",
      "0x3df59e94eb7b41cc6f037a6a7fcf7a3518ea13073bedc3c0c15bd24e83e83d66",
      "0x9792735f46ccc0fbff09e6e205f9f90474bf27cbbbd845a95e7303da880cc057",
      "0xc27ec22620bd0ecfb4664706013a1e386828ab77fe71c7218bb1b24a6fc8c085",
      "0x7d512708738df8b80fea2741e844251b21d2542cb14b39a2cb4c2c570433286e"
    ],
    "transactionsRoot": "0x4a56dfcf3e04202b262775c88d5946120918c999465d68b1cf96e9262248a39d",
    "uncles": []
  }
}
```